# Why is an empty val prepended to a JSON array not used by the Selection element?

Tags: json, meteor, drop-down-menu, spacebars, meteor-helper

In my Meteor app, I am populating a "States" select element like this:

main.html:

```
<select id="stateorprovince" name="stateorprovince">
    {{#each statesAndProvinces}}
      <option title="{{hint}}">{{abbrcode}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

main.js:

```
Template.addJobLoc.helpers({
  statesAndProvinces: function() {
    return [{
      "hint": "Alabama",
      "abbrcode": "AL"
    }, {
    . . .
```

Since "AL" (Alabama) was always the default value, I wanted to add a default value of an empty string, so I changed the helper to this:

```
Template.addJobLoc.helpers({
  statesAndProvinces: function() {
    return [{
      "hint": "No selection",
      "abbrcode": ""
    }, {
      "hint": "Alabama",
      "abbrcode": "AL"
    }, {
    . . .
```

However, "AL" still displays as the first/default value - why? How can I make the default val an empty string?

Comment: Are you hitting Refresh or loading the page by following a link / retyping it into the address bar? You are probably just observing the browser remembering your previous selection and switching to it on page load.

Comment: I come to the same conclusion as Quentin, there appears to be nothing wrong with your code, it must be browser behaviour if you are not seeing blank default value in the dropdown.  http://meteorpad.com/pad/NCrbnbJHDpaYkEjEz/statesAndProvinces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler pattern:

```
<select id="stateorprovince" name="stateorprovince">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    {{#each statesAndProvinces}}
      <option title="{{hint}}">{{abbrcode}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Just use your original helper with the list of states.